# Steam api endpoint 'appdetails' params

Tags: api, rest, steam

[https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids={APPID}](https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=%7BAPPID%7D)

So, steam store api has an endpint `api/appdetails` that takes in *appids* parameter. The thing is, I would like to receive data about multiple apps. Judging for the `appids` parameter name, it can accept multiple values. Already tried `appids=730,100`, `appids[0]=730&appids[1]=100` and `apppids=730&appids=100`, neither worked the way I'd like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI, app ids as csv like your first attempt does work, you just need to set the filters parameter to price_overview. When I tried this it did indeed work, but I got no actual data back so I'm not sure how useful it is.

Comment: Thanks, guess I will have to send requests one by one, as I'd like to get mostly game names and not prices.

Comment: If that's all you're after, maybe consider this endpoint: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/